# Rows to Columns

Tags: linux, python-2.7, row, multiple-columns

I have my text file as follows:

```
TOPIC:  0 161416.0

the 10758.0
. 6330.0
, 5043.0
<unknown> 4591.0
in 4521.0
be 4476.0
of 3759.0

TOPIC:  1 93549.0

the 6957.0
, 4170.0
of 3624.0
. 3468.0
<unknown> 2321.0
be 2121.0
a 2073.0
in 1998.0
```

and so on. I have about 2000 topics in the file.

I already tried out

```
awk -v RS= '/----/{next}{gsub(/\n/,",")}7' Input File
```

But, I get the output as

```
TOPIC:  0 161416.0

the 10758.0,. 6330.0,, 5043.0,<unknown> 4591.0,in 4521.0,be 4476.0,of     3759.0

TOPIC:  1 93549.0

the 6957.0,, 4170.0,of 3624.0,. 3468.0,<unknown> 2321.0,be 2121.0,a 2073.0,in 1998.0
```

But I need the output to be

I want to have my output as follows:

```
TOPIC:  0 161416   TOPIC:  1 93549.0  ........... TOPIC:  N

. 6330.0            , 4170.0                      .
.                   of 3624.0                     .
.                   .                             .
.                   .                             .
.                   .
```

so on....

Here they are the words/topics and their respective weights/values.

PS: Each topics essentially don't have the same number of elements. Topic 0 might have 100 elements, topic 1 might have 300 elements and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lne 'chomp;
           if (/Topic: .*/) { push @t, [$_] }
           else { push @{ $t[-1] }, $_ }
           $max = @{ $t[-1] } if @{ $t[-1] } > $max;
           }{
           for $i (0 .. $max-1) {
               print join "\t", map $t[$_][$i], 0 .. $#t
           }' < input > output
```

Comment: Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -1 at -e line 3, <> line 1. Still getting this error :(

Comment: @Krupa_Raghu: Then please provide an input sample that also produces the error.

Comment: Isn't it just `Topic` versus `TOPIC`?

Comment: I have given my input instead of the pattern. I have given the exact format. Please have a look

Comment: @Krupa_Raghu: Just replace `Topic` with `TOPIC` in the code then.

Comment: Unix is the operating system, not a programming language. It works for me for the input you provided.

Comment: Not working for the entire file again. I don't how to make it work. When I did it for a sample file it worked. Now again the same error.

Comment: @Krupa_Raghu: The error should indicate the line number in the input file. Try to start your research there.